# How to load the id, but not the object if it doesn't exist in a ManyToOne mapping

Tags: java, jpa

I have two objects Customer and Transaction. They look something like this:

```
@Entity
class Transaction {
    @Id
    long id;        

    @Column("CUSTOMER_ID")
    long customerId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="CUSTOMER_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false, nullable=false)
    Customer customer
    ...
}

@Entity
class Customer {
    @ID
    long id;
    ...
}
```

The problem is we use fake customer numbers to identify some types of transactions. It's a legacy practice that I can do nothing to change and various other processes outside my control rely on it.

What I'd like to be able to do is get the customer number back for the dummy customer transactions and just have a null customer on my transaction object. For transactions that aren't to dummy customers I'd like to have the customer object set. Ideally I'd rather not have to test for the dummy customer numbers and issue separate queries.

How do I write a query and map my object to do that? Right now everything I try, I end up with an EntityNotFound exception for the dummy policy IDs.

Answer (score 0):

using UNION you could select the proper customer record, unioned with a default 'NO SUCH CUSTOMER' record, make sure the default value comes second by ordering apropriatly and fetching only the first result.

Answer (score 0):

In JPA if the ManyToOne does not reference anything you should just get null.  Not sure how you are getting EntityNotFound.  It may be a specific issue to your JPA provider.

Comment: I'm using hibernate. The problem isn't when the CUSTOMER_ID is null, it's when it's not null but doesn't reference an object. We have specific dummy customer IDs that don't have a corresponding Customer object. As I said above, unfortunately they're a legacy artefact that I cannot remove as other processes and systems rely on them.

Comment: This issue is specific to the way Hibernate uses proxies to implement lazy loading, other JPA implementations that do not use proxies would not have this issue.  Making it EAGER should resolve the issue.

Comment: It's not that the entities aren't be loaded when they exist, that works fine. The problem is when an entity doesn't exist, when it's one of the dummy customers it throws an exception.